# Code to display Django (Reverse) related table throws error

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I'm quite new to Django and practicing Models section of Django by following its official tutorial. I also created a project of my own and try to apply similar concepts.

This is my models.py;

```py
from django.db import models

class Experience(models. Model):

    o01_position = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    o02_year_in = models.DateField(null=True)
    o03_year_out = models.DateField(null=True)
    o04_project = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    o05_company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    o06_location = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.o01_position}

class Prjdesc(models.Model):

    o00_key = models.ForeignKey(
        Experience, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    o07_p_desc = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.o07_p_desc

class Jobdesc(models.Model):

    o00_key = models.ForeignKey(Experience, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    o08_job_desc = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.o08_job_desc
```

Now when I run below command in Python/Django shell it runs as expected with the related data.

```
>>> x = Experience.objects.get( pk = 2 )
>>> x
<Experience: Head Office Technical Office Manager>
```

Below two also work as expected:

```
>>> y = Prjdesc.objects.get( pk = 11 )
>>> y
<Prjdesc: Description 1>

>>> x.prjdesc_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Prjdesc: Description 1>, <Prjdesc: Description 2>]>
```

However this expression does not return anything although it should return its related record in Experience Class.

```
>>> y.experience
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Prjdesc' object has no attribute 'experience'
```

Could you tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: access to the primary model is carried out through the associated field from the primary model: Prjdesc.objects.get(id=1).o00_key.o01_position

Comment: @inquirer I got this perfectly and what you have written also works however I still do not get how this:  [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial02/) works. (">>> c.question" line neart the bottom.)

Comment: I'm also trying to replicate this by; `c = x.prjdesc_set.create(o07_p_desc='Description 5')` and afterwards `c.experience` but it does not work. Thanks anway.

Comment: @BlueHawk77 What does `c.experience` return? It should return `o01_position` as you return in `__str__()` method in `Experience` model.

Comment: Strangely it returns this; `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Prjdesc' object has no attribute 'experience'` This behavior is not matching the behavior described in here: [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial02/) (">>> c.question" line neart the bottom.) I should be missing something

Comment: I just tried and my above approach (the one at the question) `y = Prjdesc.objects.get( pk = 11 )` and `y.experience` at the tutorial set and it worked for the model in tutorial. I tried `Choice.objects.get( pk = 1 ).question` and I get expected result of `<Question: What's new?>` I do not get why it does not work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in one of the comments above:

> Strangely it returns this; Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  AttributeError: 'Prjdesc' object has no attribute 'experience'.

You simply need to write `c.o00_key` not `c.experience`, you confused with official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial02/), they give their field  name also as `experince`.

Generally, [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) is created using model name in `smallcase` while defining field, and the `related_name` sets to model name as prefix and `_set` as suffix by default, so it will be `prjdesc_set` in your case or you can override it by using [`ForeignKey.related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in the field.

With your current models use this:

```py
>>> x = Experience.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> x
<Experience: Head Office Technical Office Manager>

>>> c = x.prjdesc_set.create(o07_p_desc='Description 5')
>>> c
<Prjdesc: Description 5>

>>> c.o00_key
>>> c
<Experience: Head Office Technical Office manager>
```

> **Note:** Also it's better to use [`f stings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) in the [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method, so in your models.py:

```py
class Experience(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.o01_position}"

class Prjdesc(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.o07_p_desc}"

class Jobdesc(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.o08_job_desc}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both your time and your answer. As you stated I was confused by the official documentation model as they have both named the table and one column the same. In fact this is a bad practice which they should try not to do as a newcomer like me can easily confuse one with another. All is clear now. Have a great day !!!

Comment: @BlueHawk77 Yes, API reference of Django docs required basic knowledge of key concepts (I mean topics) first , also mentioned in the docs as [How the documentation is organised?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/#how-the-documentation-is-organized)

Comment: @BlueHawk77 not only you were confused by the same names.

Comment: @inquirer Do you mean you were also? ;) At first, I was too, see comment below the question.

Comment: @SunderamDubey at the beginning of the study, I also could not understand what was the matter).

Comment: @inquirer You are talking about beginning, but I was about 2 days ago, but then I remember suddenly after looking at `related_name`.

Answer (score 1):

If you pay attention:

```
c = q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Just hacking again', votes=0)
```

there is a call through _set. But not at all:

```
q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
```

followed by:

```
q.choice# which will throw the same error
```

By using the primary model, you can get the data associated with it from the secondary model. To do this, a special property (object) with the name **secondary model_set**  is created in the primary model by default. In your case, for example:

```
x = Experience.objects.get(pk=1)
x.prjdesc_set.all()
```

That is, we get all the values of the secondary model with pk=1 of the primary one (one-to-many access).

If you need to get the value from the primary model from the secondary model, then as already mentioned:

```
Prjdesc.objects.get(id=1).o00_key.o01_position
```

In this case, **get** is used, that is, the value should be one, if more is expected, then **filter** should be applied.

Comment: I would also like to thank you for your assistance. As I have written below Dubey's answer below, there was a duplicate naming at official documentation which confused me. Have a great weekend !